# In Portrait its working fine but in landscape its coming on half screen i am usin wAny hAny size class

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

[image]

[image]

In Portrait its working fine but in landscape its coming on half screen i am using wAny hAny size class please help me to solve this.

Comment: Your layout constraints are probably wrong.

Comment: No sir its absolutely fine

Comment: What are your layout constraints?

Comment: from left ,right,top,bottom its 10

Comment: Are your constraints installed in all size classes? (If you added them while being in a size class other than (Any | Any) they'll only be installed on that particular size class and not on the others.

Comment: And what's the blue bar at the bottom in your first screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Control click the view and drag your mouse to the view controller. You should get a menu to pop up with a list of constraint options.

[image]

For what you are doing, I would just do "Equal Widths", "Equal Heights", "Center Horizontally in Container", and "Center Vertically in Container".

That should properly size and center it despite screen orientation.